# pandas how to calculate delta only given month and day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following `df`,

```
doc_date    date_string
2019-06-03  WW0306
2019-06-07  EH0706
```

`doc_date` is of `datetime64` with `year-month-day` format; `date_string` is of string `dtype` with `day/month` or `month/day` format if non-digit characters removed;

```
df['date_string'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```

How to convert `date_string` into `datetime64`, and set a flag `within_180` to `true` if `date_string` is within +/- 180 days of `doc_date` not considering that it does not have the year and any date format that it converted to;

```
 df['within_180'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.between(x.doc_date -
                                          Timedelta(180, unit='d'),
                                          x.doc_date +
                                          Timedelta(180, unit='d')))
```

the result should looks like,

```
doc_date    date_string    within_180
2019-06-03  WW0306         true
2019-06-07  EH0706         true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you convert the `date_string` column to datetime after `replace` and use[`series.dt.dayofyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html) to access the day of year for both the columns and compare with [`series.le()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df['date_string'].str.replace(r'\D+', ''),format='%d%m')
#df.doc_date=pd.to_datetime(df.doc_date) convert to datetime if not already datetime
df['withith_180'] = (df.doc_date.dt.dayofyear-s.dt.dayofyear).le(180)
```

---

```
    doc_date date_string  withith_180
0 2019-06-03      WW0306         True
1 2019-06-07      EH0706         True
```

Comment: I think just comparing `dayofyear` of `1900-MM-DD` against `dayofyear` of `doc_date` will miss the edge case of leap year.

Comment: @AndyL. yeah, the prob is we dont have year here.

Comment: yeah, the question is ambiguous. It seems it is asking for assumption on the year.